# Call multi methods in model or call in controller, CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am new in OOP and CodeIgniter. When I separate methods of model, I called it in controller. But now, I find another way is to call it in the model. Is it good or not to use the way bellow:

Model:

```
function q_insert($id) {
  //get value from q_select model
  $s = $this->q_select($id);
  $data = array(
           'User' => $s->row()->Name;
         }
  $this->db->insert('tblPOS', $data);
}

function qu_select($id) {
 $this->db->select('Name, ID');
 $this->db->from('tblUser');
 $this->db->where('ID', $id);
}
```

Controller:

```
function create_pos($id) {
  $this->model->q_insert($id);
}
```

Comment: Its fine to call a model function within that model, it depends on the requirement...

Comment: I wrote 'New' it means that I am not good enough. Sorry

Comment: @teresko: Its not one of the worst frameworks!

Comment: @plainjane , oh, but it is. It is filled with bad practices, PHP4 artifacts, relies on global state and completely misses the point of MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage is fine. It will be a bad practice in cases like if you are setting values to $this->db object and calling another method which has another set of values for DB class. This might get you into problems

Bad Practice

```
function get_users(){
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->where('a', $a);
$children = $this->_get_children();
$this->db->where_not_in($children);
$this->db->get('parents');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you manage your Controller requests from  your Models itself, its absolutely fine.

Say for example, if you are saving a record.

If the submitted form data has (hidden) id value, then you are updating a record, otherwise, you are adding a new record.

If you call a function from controller after form submit with all submitted data, you can check in Model itself whether you are adding or updating the data.

Depending upon that, you can call either insert or update function.

Your approach/concept is absolutely fine and most welcome.